# Values in sysctl.conf not applied at startup

Tags: macos, mac

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.4 and have the following in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
kern.sysv.shmmax: 16777216
kern.sysv.shmmin: 1
kern.sysv.shmmni: 256
kern.sysv.shmseg: 8
kern.sysv.shmall: 65536
```

However, these values are not applied at startup and I have to run `sysctl -w ...` manually to change these vars an launch Postgres. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have colons separating names from values. They should be equals signs. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sysctl.conf.5.html) for the correct format.